# How to start a MAUI Windows (desktop) app from e.g. explorer?

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I am new to MAUI (who aren't?).
Built the template app which works fine when launched by F5 from VS2022 (17.2.0 Preview 3.0 with MAUI 6.0.300-rc.1).

How to launch from explorer like any other .exe?
(I don't find much on web yet, related to publishing such an app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not new to .NET MAUI! We're currently working through bugs to make the publishing scenarios work for Windows.

You can find my write-up so far [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4329) but that mostly writes about creating an MSIX, which is what you need for the store, but you can also side-load. The "unpackaged" scenario as this is called has some things we need to work out before GA.

Comment: wow, if that issue page doesnt make WPF and WinForm devs run and hide I'm not sure what will...